# Anchor Tag in Next.js

Tags: html, next.js

I'm tryin got use an anchor tag in Next.js

I don't get any console errors when I set it up and click the link, but the page does not jump to the id tag.

This [issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/11109) on github suggests that people need to figure out a lot of custom code to use anchors. That can't be right.

I have:

```
const links = [
    { label: 'Solutions', href: '#solutions', id: 'solutions' },
    
  ]

 <NavLink.Desktop key={index} href={link.href} id={link.id}>
            {link.label}
          </NavLink.Desktop>
```

I get no errors, but the page does not jump to the label that has an id of 'solutions'.

Does anyone know how to solve this, or where to go for ideas on how - it can't be intented that complex custom code is required to use an anchor tag?

Comment: Where does `NavLink.Desktop` come from?

Comment: chakra-ui for react

Comment: href: '#solutions', id: 'solutions' . For one thing, your href is same as the ID of the link you are clicking.  It is not referencing ownself?

Comment: i shouldnt need the href if its an anchor tag, but lots of the chakra ui examples are confusing on this point. it's just a nav bar with links to move around the page. none of the anchor tag approaches work. it does work if i use the link.href to move to another page, but not for a div id

Comment: The `id` for the anchor should be set on the element you want to link to, not on the link itself.

Comment: Please can you provide an example of the solution you evisage. I have tried every variation I can think of.

Comment: const links = [
    { label: 'Solutions', href: '#targetid', id: 'solutions' },
    
  ] If the targetid is also solutions then you have a duplicate ID on your page. Rename it to something else.

Comment: I still dont understand this. what would the tag the id of the div I am trying to scroll to as when i I use your suggestion @Ismail? I tried amending the const per your suggestion, when I click the label, the url updates to http://localhost:3000/#targetid but does not cause a scroll to the anchor link. Thank you for trying to help. I wish i was clever enough to find a clue in your note.

Comment: @juliomalves - i tried removing the id definition from teh const altogether and just using href in that const (with href="solutions" and alternatively href="#solutions) and then in the content for the div i want to scroll to, i have an attribute called id: set to 'solutions' and alternatively "#solutions". All of these fail. I have tried amending the attribute name to replace 'id' with 'name' as I have seen some posts describe this approach. It doesn't work either.

Comment: targetid was used as an example, it should be the ID of the tag you are trying to scroll to.

Comment: Okay, well thank you for trying to help. I've tried that many times and with many variations. It isn't working. There may be extra steps required to use anchor tags in next.js. Thank you again.

Comment: @Mel Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help us replicate the issue?

Answer (score 6):

Chakra UI has a Link component

```
<Link href='https://chakra-ui.com' isExternal>
Chakra Design system <ExternalLinkIcon mx='2px' />
</Link>
```

If you use the regular anchor tags

```
<Link href="#anchor_one">Menu one</Link>
<Link href="#anchor_two">Menu two</Link>
```

Then you can add the id for the anchors to the sections you want to navigate into

```
<div id="anchor_one" />
<div id="anchor_two" />
```

This can be either pages or components.

I hope this helped a little bit.

Answer (score 3):

As said by @juliomalves in the comments, you have to specify the **id** attribute on the element in which you wish to navigate to. Not on the anchor tag.

> The id for the anchor should be set on the element you want to link to, not on the link itself.

The below code works for me in Next.js -

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <a href="#section">Click</a>

      <section
        style={{ marginTop: "1000px", marginBottom: "1000px" }}
        id="section"
      >
        <h1>Test</h1>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Your code should look like this -

```
const links = [{ label: 'Solutions', href: '#solutions', id: 'solutions' }]

<NavLink.Desktop 
     key={index} 
     href={link.href}
     // id={link.id} - This is wrong, as you're referring to the same element
>
   {link.label}
</NavLink.Desktop>

// Rather set the id attribute in a separate div/section element
<div id={link.id}>
   <h2>Solutions</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this. Thank you for the suggestion. It doesn't work to move the screen to focus on the anchor tag in the div marked with that id. the url address is updated to append #solutions to the end of which ever path is current at the point when i click on the navbar link (but the anchor does not move to the relevant div tag)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to scroll to anchor programatically using Router.push:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const Foo = () => {
  const { push } = useRouter()

  const handleClick = () => {
    push("#blah")
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Scroll</button>
      <div>Foo</div>
      <div>Bar</div>
      <div id="blah">Blah</div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Next.js recognises that you are passing something that is not a link to a new page and will concat it (in the example `#blah`) to the end of the URL.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi, thanks for this suggestion, but the when I click the button, it just jumps to the end of the page instead of the div id. I've tried adding very long lorem ipsum to make sure this was happening in this way. It isn't jumping to the anchor tag.

Comment: `push("/page#header")` this works? Click to go to another page and scroll to anchor?

Answer (score 0):

maybe try

```
const links = [
{ label: 'Solutions', href: '#solutions', id: 'solutions' },

 ]

<NavLink.Desktop key={index} href={links[0].href} id={links[0].id}>
        {link.label}
</NavLink.Desktop>
```

since you only have 1 element in the links array, if you have multiple just map through the array

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. i have other elements, so this would not help me. thank you just the same.

Comment: Just to make sure you are mapping through the array while assigning the hrefs right? And did you have look at inspect element to verify if the desired href was assigned to it? Avoid using id same as the one in href by the way.

Answer (score -1):

Have a read about Link from next/link its a built in feature.

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/hello-world/pages/index.js#L7

Comment: I've read te documentation. The implementatoin is exposing a field that does not seem to be supported. The github issue link in my post provides some context.

Comment: I have read these documents. They explain how to link to another page. This question is asking about an anchor link to another div on the same page.